# Reading data from external device

Tags: python, arduino

I need some help with data reading.
In my situation, I have an Arduino Uno connected via USB to the RPi.
The Arduino is sending data to the RPi with *Serial.write()*. The Arduino outputs 128 bytes each read out period.

Part of the Arduino code which produces the output looks like this:

```
void loop()
{
  unsigned char ADC_value;
  unsigned char first_byte = 0;

  if(conv_complete)
  {
    if(first_sample)
    {
      first_sample = 0;
      Serial.write(first_byte);
    }
    else
    {
      ADC_value = ADCH;
      Serial.write(ADC_value);
    }
    conv_complete = 0;
  }
}
```

Currently I have my Python code like this:

```
import time, serial
import numpy as np
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0',115200)
start = time.time()
PERIOD_OF_TIME = 300
reading = ser.read()
f = open('data.txt','a')
while reading is not None:
    f.write(reading)
    reading = ser.read()
if time.time()>start+PERIOD_OF_TIME:break
```

I tried using *ser.read()* but the output I got are a bunch of symbols. If I modify the code in Arduino to *Serial.println()* I can read the data with *ser.readline()* on the RPi side but the data obtained doesn't have 128 samples in a period (I only got around 40 samples in a period). I think this could be due to the *Serial.println()* command which converted 3 bytes into an integer value and these are not usable for me.

I understand there is a difference with *Serial.println* and *Serial.write*.
*Serial.write* writes binary data to the serial port and *Serial.print* prints data to the serial port as human-readable ASCII text.

I want to convert the received data to *uint8* format by adding another line of python code like this:

```
x = np.fromfile(f,dtype=np.uint8)
```

So that I would be able to see values (0-255). I'm still having trouble with this. Any advise?
Any help is much appreciated.  :)

Comment: Hello, and welcome to the RPi SE! Could you post more of your code - how are you opening the ports, what are your baudrate settings, ...? I guess you are using pySerial, right?

Comment: Hi there, I had made appropriate edits to my post. Sorry for the lack of details.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using pySerial.

You need to set a timeout when you instantiate the serial class.

See https://pyserial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pyserial_api.html for details.

Without a timeout readline will block until a newline is read.

Your program logic will have to deal with readline returning with a timeout.

Comment: Thank you for the link and explanation. I will proceed to carry out further modifications and tests.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to read binary data you need to do a bit more planning (or specify in more detail what you are sending).

`serial.readline()` reads data until a newline.

`serial.read(n)` reads n bytes (unless you have set a timeout).

So you could use `serial.read(4)` if you were sending bytes in groups of 4.
You need to synchronise the reading so you start at the group.

EDIT **__________**

The data is already bytes!!

If all you want to do is display the bytes (in hex) read try the following (Note I am not a Python expert - this is much easier in c)

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import serial
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0',115200)
read_byte = ser.read()
while read_byte is not None:
    read_byte = ser.read()
    print '%x' % ord(read_byte)
```

Comment: Hi there, I apologise for the extra posts. I had cleared the previous posts and will keep to this post. I had made appropriate edits to this post by adding more details to it.